# Call a Rest API from Apache Beam

Tags: java, api, rest, apache-beam

Context: I'm creating objects that contain some data, and in my case, data cannot find from one source. So I'm consuming data coming from a Kinesis stream and need to call a Rest API providing some data that came from the stream to get some other fields required to create the final object.

Question: I know that Apache beam is not yet released as an official way to communicate with Rest APIs. But looks like it is still in progress - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1946

What I want to know is the best and proper way to call a Rest API inside the beam pipeline. Highly appreciate it if you can share any resources/examples along with your feedback's.

Tried the standard(HttpClient API) java way of calling Rest API, but I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve this. Am expecting answers and some resources if possible.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Beam offers a way to define arbitrary computations in the form of `DoFn` UDF implementation used with [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) transforms. This should allow you to add logic that connects to any REST API. Currently there's no official REST Beam connector as you mentioned but this should not block you from connecting to any custom API within your pipeline.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!